# How do you change column names to lowercase with linux and store the file as it is?

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to change the column names to lowercase in a csv file. I found the code to do that online but I dont know how to replace the old column names(uppercase) with new column names(lowercase) in the original file. I did something like this:
`$cat head -n1 xxx.csv | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"`

But it simply just prints out the column names in lowercase, which is not enough for me.
I tried to add `sed -i` but it did not do any good. Thanks!!

Comment: If you're using head you mean to replace the "row names", not "column names", right? Adding input and expected output is always the best way to dispel inaccuracies in the problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) (readability winner) :

concise way:

```
awk 'NR==1{print tolower($0);next}1' file.csv
```

or using ternary operator:

```
awk '{print (NR==1) ? tolower($0): $0}' file.csv
```

or using if/else statements:

```
awk '{if (NR==1) {print tolower($0)} else {print $0}}' file.csv
```

#### To change the file for real:

```
awk 'NR==1{print tolower($0);next}1' file.csv | tee /tmp/temp
mv /tmp/temp file.csv
```

For your information, [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) using the *in place* edit switch `-i` do the same: it use a temporary file under the hood.

You can check this by using :

```
strace -f -s 800 sed -i'' '...' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -i -pe '$_=lc() if $.==1' file.csv
```

It replace the file *on the fly* with `-i` switch

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to tell it to replace the first line with all lower-case and then print the rest as-is:

```
sed '1s/.*/\L&/' ./xxx.csv
```

Redirect the output or use `-i` to do an in-place edit.

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ echo -e "COL1,COL2,COL3\nFoO,bAr,baZ" | sed '1s/.*/\L&/'
col1,col2,col3
FoO,bAr,baZ
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is to apply the changes to the original file, so IMHO the `-i` option should be explicitly used in the sed command, or the redirection to a temp file and then the move overwriting the original file.

Comment: Disagree. Always safer to verify the change first.